# Drawing sloped lines within table in html and css

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

I would like to create a table that looks like this using css and html. I have no idea how to go about solving the problem.

I'm able to create the progress bar with simple rectangular divs and css. I'm also able to make the table with the descriptions. I'm not sure how to go about creating the row with angled sides. Any help would be great.

[image]

I am doing this in Angular but I don't think the framework used is important to the solution.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <div class="progress" *ngIf="screenerStats$ | async as screenerStats">
        <div
          class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
          role="progressbar"
          [attr.aria-valuenow]="screenerStats?.percentScreened"
          [style.width.%]="screenerStats?.percentScreened"
          aria-valuemin="0"
          aria-valuemax="100"
          [matTooltip]="
            (screenerStats?.screened | number) + ' screened by you.'
          "
        >
          <span>{{ screenerStats?.screened | number }} Completed</span>
        </div>
        <div
          class="progress-bar progress-bar-info"
          role="progressbar"
          [attr.aria-valuenow]="screenerStats?.percentAvailable"
          [style.width.%]="screenerStats?.percentAvailable"
          aria-valuemin="0"
          aria-valuemax="100"
          [matTooltip]="
            (screenerStats?.available | number) +
            ' available for screening by you.'
          "
        >
          <span>{{ screenerStats?.available | number }} Available </span>
        </div>
        <div
          class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning"
          role="progressbar"
          [attr.aria-valuenow]="screenerStats?.percentUnavailable"
          [style.width.%]="screenerStats?.percentUnavailable"
          aria-valuemin="0"
          aria-valuemax="100"
          [matTooltip]="
            (screenerStats?.unavailable | number) +
            ' unavailable for screening by you (due to sufficient screening by others).'
          "
        >
          <span>{{ screenerStats?.unavailable | number }} Unavailable</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <th>{{ screenerStats?.percentScreened | number }} Completed</th>
   <th>{{ screenerStats?.percentAvailable | number }} Available</th>
   <th>{{ screenerStats?.percentUnavailable | number }} Unavailable</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>{{ screenerStats?.screened | number }} studies screened by you.</td>
   <td>{{ screenerStats?.available | number }} studies available for screening by you.</td>
   <td>{{ screenerStats?.unavailable | number }} studies unavailable for screening by you (due to suffucient screening by others).</td>   
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Post the code you have so far, and maybe some of the things you've tried. Perhaps this would be done with a shape mask or SVG shapes?

Comment: I've added the code I've done so far

Comment: That code appears to be from an Angular templater. Can you post the actual *rendered* HTML and CSS that goes along with it?  No one can work with the code you have posted.  You are asking a CSS question, not an Angular question

Comment: Does this have to be a table element or are you free to use divs?